# Output in two different columns based on field value

Tags: sql, oracle

I work with Oracle SQL and I'm a noob.

```
    table:example
    +--------------+--------------+-------------+
    | id_nr        |  code        | subtype     |
    +-------------------------------------------+
    | 1445         | 40D1343      | DRG         |
    | 1445         | 23423asas    | PROC        |
    | 1234         | 234.34K      | PROC        |
    | 1233         | 2230S        | DRG         |
    | 1233         | 996k         | DRG         |
    | 1233         | 55239        | PROC        |
    +--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

Based on two values in the field *subtype* ('PROC' or 'DRG'), the *code* field value from the same row should be output in two different columns ('PROC' -> *ipc_code*, 'DRG' -> *asc_code*).

```
table:example
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| id_nr        | subtype     | ipc_code    | asc_code  |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 1445         | DRG         |             | 40D1343   |
| 1445         | PROC        | 23423asas   |           |
| 1234         | PROC        | 234.34K     |           |
| 1233         | DRG         |             | 2230S     |
| 1233         | DRG         |             | 996k      |
| 1233         | PROC        | 55239       |           |
+--------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want `case`:

```
select id_nr, subtype,
       (case when subtype = 'PROC' then code end) as ipc_code,
       (case when subtype = 'DRG' then code end) as asc_code
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you, brother. I'll check it on Monday.